# starry regular icosahedron

Tags: riemannian-geometry

La estructura del pentágono regular estrellado se puede describir mediante una curva f(t) que no se corta a sí misma en una superficie de Riemann de dos hojas. Cómo onstruir en una variedad tridimensional el icosaedro regular estrellado de séptima especie de Kepler-Poinsot? (English:  great icosahedron). Se busca una función f(u,v) sobre una variedad tridimensional que produzca una superficie homotópica de la del icosaedro y  que recorra siete veces la esfera pero sin cortarse.

Comment: ¿Puedes proporcionar un link al pentágono regular estrellado que describes, y puedo traducir tu pregunta?

Comment: I tried my hand at a translation -- please check if this is what you intended. I assume you're referring to the "seventh" stellation as shown e.g. [here](http://www.korthalsaltes.com/model.php?name_en=stellations%20of%20the%20icosahedron) and [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d8/Seventh_stellation_of_icosahedron.png) (linked from [here](http://math.wikia.com/wiki/Icosahedron#Stellations))?

Comment: Me refiero a uno de los cuatro poliedros regulares estrellados descubiertos por Kepler y estudiados por Poinsot y por Cauchy, en particular el que tiene doce vértices, veinte caras que son triángulos equiláteros pero los ángulos sobre los vértices son pentaedros estrellados. Algunos le llaman el gran icosaedro. Adjunto un link. http://www.korthalsaltes.com/photo/Great_Icosahedron_large.jpg

Comment: En el plano el pentágono estrellado se puede recorrer a partir de un vértice siguiendo una línea homotópica a una curva cerrada con dos bucles que se cortan pero que se puede construir como curva cerrada simple sobre la superficie de Riemann de la función raiz cuadrada de {(z-1)/(z+1)} como la imagen de una circunferencia con centro 1 y radio 1.